# Change current process environment's LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: python, shared-libraries, environment-variables

Is it possible to change environment variables of current process?

More specifically in a python script I want to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that on import of a module 'x' which depends on some `xyz.so`, `xyz.so` is taken from my given path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

is there any other way to dynamically change path from where library is loaded?

**Edit**: I think I need to mention that I have already tried thing like
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = mypath
os.putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', mypath)

but these modify the env. for spawned sub-process, not the current process, and module loading doesn't consider the new LD_LIBRARY_PATH

**Edit2**, so question is can we change environment or something so the library loader sees it and loads from there?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856116/changing-ldlibrarypath-at-runtime-for-ctypes? You aren't actually asking how to change the environment, but rather how to change where python loads libraries from.

Comment: ok! i will say this is duplicate, but no it is not abt python it about changing environment, e.g. in a c app which loads a dynamic lib A, can we change environ so that A is loaded from our path of choice

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The reason

```
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = ...
```

doesn't work is simple: this environment variable controls behavior of the dynamic loader (`ld-linux.so.2` on Linux, `ld.so.1` on Solaris), but the loader only looks at `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` once at process startup. Changing the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the current process *after* that point has no effect (just as the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856116/changing-ldlibrarypath-at-runtime-for-ctypes) question says).

You do have some options:

A. If you know that you are going to need `xyz.so` from `/some/path`, and control the execution of python script from the start, then simply set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your liking (after checking that it is not already so set), and re-execute yourself. This is what `Java` does.

B. You can import `/some/path/xyz.so` via its absolute path *before* importing `x.so`. When you then import `x.so`, the loader will discover that it has already loaded `xyz.so`, and will use the already loaded module instead of searching for it again.

C. If you build `x.so` yourself, you can add `-Wl,-rpath=/some/path` to its link line, and then importing `x.so` will cause the loader to look for dependent modules in `/some/path`.

Comment: B, looks like an option I can use

Comment: How would option B be implemented? I think the OP implied that `/some/path/xyz.so` is a shared library that a Python module depends on; `xyz.so` does not contain a Python module itself. I have a similar situation and don't know of any way to import the library in the way you describe.

Comment: @JasonR Option B could be implemented using `import dl; dl.open("/some/path/xyz.so")`

Comment: Outstanding; thanks. Turns out that the `dl` module is deprecated as of Python 2.6, but you can do the same with `import ctypes; ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/some/path/xyz.so")`.

Comment: @JasonR Did option B work out for you? I've tried using importing the full path to the shared lib with ctypes right before importing the python module which depends on it.. but no luck.. imp.load_module() still fails

Comment: @Gregory: Yes it did. I used the syntax that I indicated in my comment above, using `ctypes`, and it worked well for me. It is possible that your Python module also depends upon some other shared libraries that haven't been loaded properly.

Comment: @JasonR It depends on a bunch, but they either were linked with full paths (standard libs) or have an rpath. The one that doesnt have an rpath always fails when imported into python.. BTW. It's a SWIG python wrapper around a shared library and SWIG suggests to use rpath/LD_LIBRARY_PATH which is exactly what I dont want to do because it's not portable/moveable/copyable

Answer (score 16):

Based on the answer from Employed Russian, this is what works for me

```
oracle_libs = os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']+"/lib/"
rerun = True

if not 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' in os.environ:
  os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ":"+oracle_libs
elif not oracle_libs in os.environ.get('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'):
  os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += ":"+oracle_libs
else:
  rerun = False

if rerun:
  os.execve(os.path.realpath(__file__), sys.argv, os.environ)
```

Comment: The execve trick is *exactly* what I needed, and it works, have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience trying to change the way the loader works for a running Python is very tricky; probably OS/version dependent; may not work.  One work-around that might help in some circumstances is to launch a sub-process that changes the environment parameter using a shell script and then launch a new Python using the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or any other environment variable paths that is required by the import modules.

```
if os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')==None: 
    os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='<PATH>'
    try:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        os.execl(sys.executable,sys.executable, *sys.argv)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
elif <path> not in os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'):
    os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ':'.join([os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH'),'<PATH>'])
    try:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        os.execl(sys.executable,sys.executable, *sys.argv)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)

# import X
```

The function os.execl will replace the current process. In UNIX a new executable will be loaded into the current process.
By having this code before the import of the 'X' module, now it will be looking for the files in the new path that was set.

[More on execl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Answer (score -10):

well, the environment variables are stored in the dictionary os.environ, so if you want to change , you can do

```
os.environ["PATH"] = "/usr/bin"
```

Comment: And I think you have to make sure you set os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] *before* the import statement for module x.

Comment: see the edit, i have already tried this and this did not work

Comment: Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in such fashion does not affect current process, as I explained in my answer.