# Python Proxy Error With Requests Library

Tags: python, http, proxy, python-requests, proxies

I am trying to access the web via a proxy server in Python. I am using the requests library and I am having an issue with authenticating my proxy as the proxy I am using requires a password.

```
proxyDict = { 
          'http'  : 'username:mypassword@77.75.105.165', 
          'https' : 'username:mypassword@77.75.105.165'
        }
r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxyDict)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxyDict)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 78, in get
:param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 65, in request
"""Sends a POST request. Returns :class:`Response` object.
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 187, in request
def head(self, url, **kwargs):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 407, in send
"""
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line     127, in proxy_from_url
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line    521, in connection_from_url
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 497, in get_host
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h6f2v6jh5dsxa@77.75.105.165'
```

How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's good manners to mark correct answers as correct

Answer (score 17):

You should remove the embedded username and password from `proxyDict`, and use the `auth` parameter instead.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxyDict = { 
          'http'  : '77.75.105.165', 
          'https' : '77.75.105.165'
        }
auth = HTTPProxyAuth('username', 'mypassword')

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies=proxyDict, auth=auth)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it solved the error but it still isn't connecting to the proxy.

When I look at the returned headers (r.headers), one of them is 'proxy-connection': 'close', which seems to mean its taking too long to connect to the proxy, is there a way to authenticate before requesting any URLs?

Comment: @MarkCollier, please try code from edited answer. It was error In first version. Added `HTTPProxyAuth`, now it should work.

Comment: from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPProxyAuth

Comment: @MarkCollier, upgrade `requests`: `pip install --upgrade requests`

Comment: @MarkCollier, you mean proxy connection error, or cannot import name? I've tested this code on local proxy server and it works. When i'm entering wrong username or password, `r.status_code` is `407`. What is yours?

Comment: @MarkCollier, what is your `requests.__version__`? I have `0.9.1`. Maybe `pip install --upgrade requests` failed, or you are testing code in interactive shell, and it has started before upgrade? Try to launch code from file.

Comment: In case this helps, this worked for me, using `requests==1.1`.

Comment: I have got the same error. I am with requests version 2.0.0. Any solution?

Comment: This fixed it for me - but does anyone know why?  The answer isn't very thorough.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having a similar problem on Windows and found the only way to get `requests` to work was to set the proxies as environment variables before I started Python. For you this would be something like this:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://77.75.105.165
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://77.75.105.165
```

You might also want to check is there's a specific port required, and if so set it after the url. For example, if the port is 8443 then do:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://77.75.105.165:8443
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://77.75.105.165:8443
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urllib` library for this.

```
from urllib import request
request.urlopen("your URL", proxies=request.getproxies())
```