# Python requests library combine HTTPProxyAuth with HTTPBasicAuth

Tags: python, proxy, http-request, python-requests

Found an example on HTTPProxyAuth usage here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8862633

But I'm hoping for a sample on usage with both HTTPProxyAuth and HTTPBasicAuth IE I need to pass a server, username and password through the proxy and a username and password to a web page...

Thanks in advance.

Richard

Comment: What are you asking for?

Comment: I need to build on the sample in the link by adding HTTPBasicAuth because not only do i need to get thru the proxy with username\password I also need to basic authenticate with the target webpage with a different username\password.

Answer (score 1):

For Basic Authentication you can Httplib2 module of python. An example is given below. For more details check [this](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples)

```
>>>import httplib2

>>>h = httplib2.Http(".cache")

>>>h.add_credentials('name', 'password')

>>>resp, content = h.request("https://example.org/chap/2", 
"PUT", body="This is text", 
headers={'content-type':'text/plain'} )
```

I don't think Httplib2 provides the proxy support. Check the [link](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/issues/detail?id=38) -

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `HTTPProxyAuth` is a child of `HTTPBasicAuth` and overrides its behaviour (please see `requests/auth.py`).

However, you can add both the required headers to your request by making a new class that implements both behaviours:

```
class HTTPBasicAndProxyAuth:
    def __init__(self, basic_up, proxy_up):
        # basic_up is a tuple with username, password
        self.basic_auth = HTTPBasicAuth(*basic_up)
        # proxy_up is a tuple with proxy username, password
        self.proxy_auth = HTTPProxyAuth(*proxy_up)

    def __call__(self, r):
        # this emulates what basicauth and proxyauth do in their __call__()
        # first add r.headers['Authorization']
        r = self.basic_auth(r)
        # then add r.headers['Proxy-Authorization']
        r = self.proxy_auth(r)
        # and return the request, as the auth object should do
        return r
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but you can provide separate BasicAuth credentials in both the Proxy AND the restricted page URLs.

For example:

```
proxies = {
 "http": "http://myproxyusername:mysecret@webproxy:8080/",
 "https": "http://myproxyusername:mysecret@webproxy:8080/",
}

r = requests.get("http://mysiteloginname:myothersecret@mysite.com", proxies=proxies)
```