# aliased Linux commands are not recognized from python (commands.getoutput)

Tags: python, linux

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.4 and I have matlab installed. Typically, in order to invoke matlab from terminal I have to type in '~/MATLAB/bin/matlab'. Obviously this is a bit annoying so  I aliased this command by adding

```
alias matlab='sh ~/MATLAB/bin/matlab'
```

to .bashrc. Now everything is golden and typing 'matlab' in the terminal (bash) works from  any directory.

The problem arises when I'm trying to invoke Matlab from a python script. having a statement like this:

```
>>> commands.getoutput('matlab')
'sh: 1: matlab: not found'
```

as it seems the alias is not being recognized.
Just to make sure:

```
>>> commands.getoutput('~/MATLAB/bin/matlab')
```

works like a charm, and

```
>>> commands.getoutput('echo $SHELL')
'/bin/bash'
```

indeed verifies that python is trying to execute the cmd in bash...

Any idea what's happening here? why isn't the alias being recognized? how/can it be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: `commands` is deprecated.  Consider using subprocess ( http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess ) instead.

Comment: Quick question -- what happens if you put your alias in `.bash_profile` also?

Comment: For background info see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environmental-variables-in-python

Comment: adding to .bash_profile doesn't help. I think ubuntu doesn't look there by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `matlab` binary path to your `PATH` environment variable.

```
PATH=~/MATLAB/bin/:$PATH
export PATH
```

Then `python` would find `matlab`:

```
>>> commands.getoutput('matlab')
```

I *think* `commands` doesn't know of your shell's current aliases. However environment variables such as `PATH` persist.

Comment: You'll have to use "export PATH=..." or else python will not pick up the PATH value.

Comment: changing PATH might add unnecessary commands from `~/MATLAB/bin`. `ln -s ~/MATLAB/bin/matlab matlab` in a directory that is already in PATH might be more suitable here

Comment: thanks for the answer. Setting PATH and exporting ('export PATH= ...' added to .bashrc) solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! i forgot the `export` keyword :)

Answer (score 4):

bash only evaluates `~/.bashrc` if it's started as an interactive shell.  If you have aliases in `/.bashrc` that you want bash to evaluate when it's run non-interactively, you could try setting the `BASH_ENV` environment variable from your Python script to point to `~/.bashrc`.

The [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) gives some more detail on interactive versus non-interactive shells and on how to use `BASH-ENV`.