# GIT/Heroku sensitive info

Tags: python, git, heroku, github, instagram

I have a django project deployed in Heroku. It uses python-instragram.

I have a 'client secret' from an instragram client that I have.
I use git/github for version control.

This client_secret is imported from an untracked file because I don't want to have it on my public github repo. I do something like this:

```
from core_keys import core_client_secret

CONFIG = {
'client_id': '83d1b794dfc24f5588378f88be67c586',
'client_secret': core_client_secret,
'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8515/oauth_callback'
}
api = client.InstagramAPI(**CONFIG)
```

I have core_keys.py added to .gitignore:

```
*/core_keys.py
```

When I deploy to heroku the app doesn't work obviously because the file that contains the client_secret was not pushed to heroku since it's in .gitignore.

How can I have this file on heroku without the need for a private repo, what approach should I use?

Comment: I don't know much about heroku, but can't you push a file somehow? As a last resort, have it received in a custom method with a POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the secrets as [config vars in the environment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: Yes this is perfect thanks! Can you maybe give me an example of how I can pass that environment var to a python file ?

Comment: You don't have to stick them in a file, just read them from the environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environmental-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference, ended up doing this:

On the terminal at my development machine:

```
heroku config:set INSTAGRAMSECRET=00000FFFFF
```

On the file where I need the environment var inside of Heroku:

```
import os
insta_secret = os.environ['INSTAGRAMSECRET']
```