# Running a .py script from bash, how can I pass a python variable back to the terminal once the .py is done running?

Tags: python, bash

For example, in bash:

```
python my_py.py
    # i get some variable my_var
```

Back to bash. I want to have $my_var!

Comment: print the variable, and only the variable to terminal. Then, in bash you can assign the output to a variable using process substitution: `myVar=$(python my.py)`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can write your variable and its value into an ini file from the python script.

In **Values.ini** file

`my_var="value"`

After executing python script, just invoke Values.ini using `.` operator

`. Values.ini`

Now your shell variable `$my_var` will be having the assigned value.
The advantage with this method is that you can assign any number of variables like this.

`var1="value1"`

`var2="value2"`

`var3="value3"`

Comment: Ok, I'll try that, thanks. By the way, in your answer you should take "In Values.ini file" out of code format. That confused me at first.

Comment: @brastein Thnx. Done :)

Comment: using `os.environ` would be both more appropriate and faster, and you can declare as many variables as you want