# Setting environment variables using Python

Tags: python

```
currentPath = os.environ['PATH']
myPath = "/auto/sw/packages/bin"
match = re.search(myPath, currentPath)
if match is not None:
    print 'PATH '+ match.group(0)+ 'FOUND'
else:
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + myPath
    print 'SET PATH: ' + os.environ['PATH']
```

In my above code, the SET PATH output is printing correctly, but its not changing the actual PATH variable when I check using 'echo $PATH'. What am I doing wrong here? A quick help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)

Comment: Are you trying to `echo $PATH` in your shell after your Python script exits? If so, it's simply not possible to alter environment variables that way. You can change environment variables in the current scope, and in subprocesses, but you cannot change the environment of the outer scope/calling process. Environment changes only propagate down, and your Python code is running in a subprocess forked from the calling process/outer shell.

Comment: Yeah. But my intention is to change the PATH from the script. There should be some way to do it. I'll post here if I succeed in that.

Answer (score 0):

1, I think the following code should be changed.

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + myPath
```

New one

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ":" + myPath
```

2, You may launch "echo $PATH" after python script quit. Try to print it in python script as followed.

```
os.system("echo $PATH")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried these two. But still its not showing the new PATH set once I come out of the script. I could see from the searches that setting an environment variable from the script isnt straight forward as I thought. Digging deeper to get the right solution.