# Django allauth not sending links with https

Tags: django, https, django-allauth

I want Django Allauth to send links like the confirm e-mail or reset password with `https`:

Something like this:

`https://example.com/ca/accounts/confirm-email/picuwfpjpptjswi50x5zb4gtsqptmwkscea445kadnbsfwcyij3fdnblery4onuq/`

According to [the official documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) only changing the following setting in `settings.py` it should work:

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"
```

But I keep getting the links with `http` instead of `https` like this:

`http://example.com/ca/accounts/confirm-email/picuwfpjpptjswi50x5zb4gtsqptmwkscea445kadnbsfwcyij3fdnblery4onuq/`

Am I missing something? Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Digging into the code a little bit, you can see that `allauth` sets the `activate_url` template context variable using Django's build in `build_absolute_uri` method:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L119

```
...
activate_url = reverse("account_confirm_email", args=[self.key])
activate_url = request.build_absolute_uri(activate_url)
ctx = {
"activate_url": activate_url,
...
}
```

Looking at the code for the `build_absolute_uri` you can see it requires a environment variable:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L153

```
def _get_scheme(self):
    return 'https' if os.environ.get("HTTPS") == "on" else 'http'
```

to return `https://` in URLs generated by this function, you need to set a `HTTPS` environment variable.

It depends on how you have set up your project, but you can [set the environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python) in your `settings.py` or `manage.py`

The following is a good post on general Django security when it comes to SSL:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure

**EDIT**

Strangely, the reset password template uses a different approach to constructing the URL:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py#L428

```
url = '%s://%s%s' % (app_settings.DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL,
    current_site.domain,
    path)
context = {"site": current_site,
    "user": user,
    "password_reset_url": url}
```

using the `DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL` settings instead

Comment: With your solution, now the Password Reset E-mail is with https, but the Confirm E-mail Address is still with http. Any idea why?

Comment: Look at the update. It seems that for the password reset template a different way of constructing the URL is used. Are you sure that the variable is being set correctly?

Comment: The Confirm E-mail Address message is still not working. I tried first to set the variable in settings.py (import os os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on") and then manually in the terminal (HTTPS="on"; export HTTPS), but I still get the Confirm E-mail Address messages with http.

Comment: Thanks to your help I managed to solve the problem! I also reported the bug and it will be solved in the next django-allauth release: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/717 Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Besides setting the "HTTPS" environment variable  and SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT,  also seems that  can be problem  when rendering template and sending mail with EmailMultiAlternatives() when .txt body is used as is in adapter.py  render_mail()
[1]: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/adapter.py

```
for ext in ["html", "txt"]:
        try:
            template_name = "{0}_message.{1}".format(template_prefix, ext)
            bodies[ext] = render_to_string(
                template_name,
                context,
                self.request,
            ).strip()
        except TemplateDoesNotExist:
            if ext == "txt" and not bodies:
                # We need at least one body
                raise
    if "txt" in bodies:
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, bodies["txt"], from_email, to)
        if "html" in bodies:
            msg.attach_alternative(bodies["html"], "text/html")
    else:
        msg = EmailMessage(subject, bodies["html"], from_email, to)
        msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
    return msg
```

For example  print(bodies[ext]) gave:

```
  "To confirm this is correct, go to " https://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/confirm-email/MjI:1kS0Mj:M5YfUf9-1Vg_TlgjVrK6vAtaLDE/ "
```

but on email is still http://

```
 http://url7514.sitename/ls/click?upn=HJL2SSWV...
```

With most devices also this worked since should be redirected still to https://, but on some didn't, so had to change in default templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt to  html extension,
after result :

`To confirm this is correct, go to https://sitename/accounts/confirm-email/M...`

Answer (score 2):

If you use django behind a proxy, you have to send https headers to django.
What works for me in apache2 was to put this on apache2

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https' env=HTTPS
```

After adding headers mod:

```
a2enmod headers
```

And this on django setting.py:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

With this all my build_absolute_uri started with https, and the same for templates, this include password recovery and auth mails.