# "CreateDC failed, Screen size info may be incorrect"

Tags: python, winapi, opengl, glut

I am trying to use `OpenGL` with python. I have Pyton 3.7.4, on a Windows 10 machine.

I downloaded `PyOpenGL` and `PyOpenGL_accelerate` from `.whl` files, and I have downloaded the `freeglut.dll` file separately and placed it in the same directory as the script I am running.

My initial scripts is just:

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

glutInit()
```

which gives the following error message:

> freeglut (foo): fgPlatformInitialize: CreateDC failed, Screen size
> info may be i ncorrect This is quite likely caused by a bad '-display'
> parameter

(Without the `freeglut.dll` file, it gives a `NameError` complaint about `glutInit()` being undefined).

I have seen error on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069038/createdc-causes-glutinit-to-fail) but a) they were doing it with C/C++ and b) the answer did not say *where* one had to make the change.

Any ideas on what I am supposed to do?

**UPDATE**

The problem may be this:

```
import os
os.getenv('DISPLAY')
# 'needs-to-be-defined'
```

What should I call this environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this piece of code at the beginning of my script and it worked:

```
import os
try:
    del os.environ['DISPLAY']
except:
    pass
```

Ideally I would delete the DISPLAY environment variable for all processes but I did not manage.

Answer (score 0):

glutInit(["-display","0"]) - as an idea based on :

https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html

Comment: The error now is "freeglut (-display): fgPlatformInitialize: CreateDC failed, Screen size info may
 be incorrect
This is quite likely caused by a bad '-display' parameter
"

Comment: I would try also empty string instead of `"0"`.