# Change Enviromental Variables from Python script

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-7-x64, python-3.4

I wrote script that checks dirs from Path and remove inaccessible dirs. Also i used snippet to run my script as admin. But when i check my Path after script execution - it's all the same.

```
import os
import sys
import win32com.shell.shell as shell

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if os.name != 'nt':
        raise RuntimeError("This script is implemented only for Windows")

    ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

    if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
        script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
        params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
        shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
        print("I am root now")

    paths = os.environ.get('Path').split(';')
    accessible_paths = []
    for path in paths:
        if os.access(path, os.R_OK):
            accessible_paths.append(path)

    new_path = ';'.join(accessible_paths)
    os.environ['Path'] = new_path

    print(new_path)
    print(new_path == os.environ['Path'])
```

So how can i actually change environment variable by Python script ?

Comment: The initial system environment variables are loaded by the session manager (smss.exe) from the registry key `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`. winlogon.exe also merges a per-user `PATH` that's loaded from the user's `HKCU\Environment` key.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os.putenv#os.putenv), setting environment variables the way you do it calls `os.putenv()`, but description of this function is not clear. Indeed, it is said the following:

> Such changes to the environment affect subprocesses started with os.system(), popen() or fork() and execv().

So I'm not sure that `os.environ` is designed to do what you expect. This is somewhat confirmed by [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python), where answer only indicates that *child* processes will be affected by this change...