# Load environment variables of bashrc into python

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, spyder

I'm trying to set the environment variable of my `.bashrc` using Spyder; in other words I'm looking for a python command that reads my `.bashrc`. Any idea?

Comment: `.bashrc` is just a file, you can read/write to it using the standard calls...

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to add a line to bashrc, set an environment variable in the parent process's environment, or set an environment variable in your own process's environment?

Comment: If you want to read the environment variables, simply use `os.environ`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python?rq=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bashrc` should automatically be loaded into the environ on login

```
import os

print os.environ
```

if you wanted to create a dictionary of values from a bash source file you could in theory do something like

```
output = subprocess.check_output("source /path/to/.bashrc;env")
env = dict(line.split("=") for line in output.splitlines() if "=" in line))
print env
```

Comment: Actually no because when I do `print os.environ['PATH']` into Spyder it returns. `/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:` which is not what I defined on my `.bashrc` (I'm on mac just to be clear). The problem is Spyder itself I suppose

Comment: yes that is because spyder is probably setting the path for you ...  Im guessing you can tell spyder to use your .bashrc somehow

Comment: see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spyderlib/jh-QCm4mtsc/mOCa0JxvfOsJ and look at davids answer ... that took me a whole 2 minutes of googling ... but it lookslike spider wants you to use a .profile file instead of .bashrc for whatever reason

Comment: Thanks for that Joran. It actually works know for the _PATH_ variable for example, however for the _PYTHON_PATH_ when doing `os.environ` in the spyder console I get _'PYTHONPATH': '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources'_. When doing that in my bash terminal `echo $PYTHONPATH` I get _/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources:/Applications/Trelis-15.0.app/Contents/MacOS_ which is what I want. So why the PYTHONPATH in Spyder is not overwritten by my .bashrc PYTHONPATH?

Comment: do you set the python_path variable in your .profile ?  I assume spyder __needs__ access to that resources directory so it alters the python path to append that path ... not replace it

Comment: furthermore if you are having this much trouble with your ide ... it begs the question is it the best IDE for you to be using?

Comment: Well I really like the matlab like features of Spyder so I would like to use it

Comment: in my .bash_profile I have the following `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Applications/Trelis-15.0.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: wait ... that talks about a `.profile` I am pretty sure it would have said `.bash_profile` if thats what they meant ...I could be wrong however

Comment: well on mac it's a bash_profile, in my .bash_profile I launch my .bashrc. Then in Spyder all the environment variables seem to be the one I set in my .bashrc, except the _PYTHONPATH_

Comment: try making a `.profile` file instead and delete your `.bash_profile` ... if spyder is actually *overwriting* your python path that is surely a bug and should be sent to the people who make spyder

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood, it's not overwriting everyhting apparently, it appends properly for example the _PATH_ variable but it seems that it's overwriting the _PYTHONPATH_. Anyway I'll let the Spyder group know about that.

Answer (score 0):

The shell's startup file is the *shell's* startup file.  You really want to decouple things so that Python doesn't have to understand Bash syntax, and so that settings you want to use from Python are not hidden inside a different utility's monolithic startup file.

One way to solve this is to put your environment variables in a separate file, and `source` that file from your `.bashrc`. Then when you invoke a shell from Python, that code can `source` the same file if it needs to.

```
# .bashrc
source $HOME/lib/settings.sh

# Python >=3.5+ code
import subprocess
subprocess.run(
    'source $HOME/lib/settings.sh; exec the command you actually want to run',
    # Need a shell; need the shell to be Bash
    shell=True, executable='/bin/bash',
    # basic hygiene
    check=True, universal_newlines=True)
```

(If you need to be compatible with older Python versions, try `subprocess.check_call()` or even `subprocess.call()` if you want to give up the safeguards by the `check_` variant in favor of being compatible all the way back to Python 2.4.)

Comment: I get:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source ~/.bashrc': 'source ~/.bashrc'