# subprocess.check_output not respecting environment variables

Tags: python, subprocess, environment-variables

While using Pythons `subprocess` module I noticed it does not seem like environment variables are being set properly. The following is an example from an IPython session showing this:

```
In [21]: subprocess.check_output(["echo", "$DUMMY"], env={"DUMMY" : "321"}, shell=True)
Out[21]: b'\n'

In [22]: subprocess.check_output(["echo", "$DUMMY"], env={"DUMMY" : "321"})
Out[22]: b'$DUMMY\n'
```

I get that the second one does not work, as it is not run by a shell. But the first one is the result you get when echoing a variable that is not set. So why does this not work? Or more probably, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I rolled back your edit -- your question should remain strictly a question.

Comment: @tripleee Sure, this works. I added it for completeness when your answer did not contain a complete code solution. I agree it's better placed in your answer like it is now.

Comment: Replace `echo $DUMMY` with `env`. You'll see that the env var is in fact set. Hint: Do arbitrary commands like `/bin/echo` perform var expansion (e.g., `$DUMMY` => `321`) or is it the responsibility of a specific program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable interpolation is a shell feature; without a shell, the string you are attempting to `echo` is simply literally `$DUMMY`.

You can add `shell=True` and then of course change the first argument to be a string instead of a list;

```
subprocess.check_call('echo "$DUMMY"', env={"DUMMY": "321"}, shell=True)
```

... or figure out a way to pass the second argument in the list directly from Python.

A better test case than `echo` is `env`; then you can see that it does in fact set the variable just like you asked it to.

Comment: Aha, so when using `shell=True`, I should give the command as a string, not as a list. Did not know that, works when I fix this. Knew it had to be something silly on my part, but couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I have been struggling with this confusion. Thank you. Is there a way to load the content of a bashrc file for example?

Comment: @BND There is of course, but you really want to avoid that,. There are several duplicates around this topic; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553576/load-environment-variables-of-bashrc-into-python shows one way to do it, but you probably want to find questions about why this is actually a bad idea.