# Different environment variables loaded into the terminal and Pycharm

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I want to call an app from its bash command using Python. I added the path to the app to the PATH environment variable, so that this work in the terminal.
However, when doing this in Pycharm, it does not work. I discovered, that is because apparently the environment variables are not all loaded in, when I call the app in Pycharm.

This is what I do in the terminal:

```
(save) philipp@philipp-Blade-15-Advanced-Model-Early-2020:~$ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 25 2020, 17:03:02) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["PATH"]
'/home/philipp/anaconda3/envs/save/bin:/home/philipp/anaconda3/condabin:/home/philipp/sumo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
```

When I run the same command in Pycharm, I get this output:

```
'/home/philipp/anaconda3/envs/save/bin:/home/philipp/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
```

The output from Pycharm is missing `/home/philipp/sumo/bin` which is where I installed my app and where I need to call it from. I looked into this a lot, but could not figure out what the issue would be... I am using the same Anaconda environment in both cases. Can you point out the issue?

Comment: It appears that the first two directories are added by your virtual environment, while `/home/philipp/sumo/bin` is added by your shell's configuration files. PyCharm isn't being started by your login shell, and so doesn't inherit a path containing `sumo/bin`.

Comment: @chepner Yes, I am adding `/home/philipp/sumo/bin` to `PATH` in the .bashrc file. Can you tell me, how I can use the same shell which the terminal uses in PyCharm as well? Also, in Windows this was working by default, I only came across the problem in Linux.

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553576/load-environment-variables-of-bashrc-into-python) says, that the `.bashrc` is loaded into `os.environ` on login. Evidently that cannot be true.

Comment: More or less, `.bashrc` is sourced when your *shell* starts. But PyCharm doesn't have your shell as the parent; it basically gets executed *for* you by another process, so it doesn't inherit from your login shell.

Comment: @chepner Ok, thanks. Then how do I insert the environment variables from bashrc when PyCharm starts a new shell? Also is there a Platform Independent method? Can you write an answer, so that I can upvote it?

Comment: I don't know; I don't use PyCharm, so I don't know what mechanism it has for configuring the environment. I just know it's not inheriting it from your shell.

Comment: Alright, but this is enough information, so that I can google for a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thing works for me.
What I did was:

1. I edited my .bashrc with `export PATH=/THIS/IS/TEST/PATH:$PATH` in the last line.
2. Exited the terminal and created a new one to refresh my instance.
3. Checked if path is properly loaded with `/THIS/IS/TEST/PATH` using `echo $PATH`.
4. Opened up pycharm from current terminal using `charm` command.
5. Copy+Pasted your code

```
import os
print(os.environ["PATH"])
```

6. Checked the printed output and I found the `/THIS/IS/TEST/PATH`.

Im running from a single terminal and using anaconda as well

Are you running pycharm from the terminal ?

---

(Alternative solution)

If it still doesn't work for you, why not just create a txt file that holds the PATH variable and refreshes whenever `~/.bashrc` was called.

for example,

1. in the `~/.bashrc` file, put this in the last line:

```
echo "$PATH" > ~/bash_path.txt
```

2. then just read the content as a variable in your python code

```
PATH = open('/absolute/path/to/bash_path.txt', 'r').read()
print(PATH)
```

which should have the same output as with the `os.environ` command.

Comment: The first solution works for me. I did not know running PyCharm from the terminal was possible and that is would initialize the PATH env variable from the `.bashrc`. I also found, that one can input environment variables, which PyCharm then uses on startup (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm)

Comment: That's good to know! I think the 2nd solution can be used in tandem with the pycharm environment setup you suggested. From what I saw from the link you sent, it still needs an env file (which is what the 2nd solution creates).