# Spark + Python - how to set the system environment variables?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm on spark-1.4.1. How can I set the system environment variables for Python?

For instance, in R,

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/Apache/spark-1.4.1")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
```

What about in Python?

```
import os
import sys

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSQL")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# Set the system environment variables.
# ref: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/sql.py
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    path = "file://" + \
        os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], "examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
else:
    path = sys.argv[1]

# Create the DataFrame
df = sqlContext.jsonFile(path)

# Show the content of the DataFrame
df.show()
```

I get this error,

df is not defined.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just asking how to set an environment variable in Python code? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python

Comment: here - `df = sqlContext.jsonFile(path)`

Answer (score -1):

Just try it like this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes

By providing `path = "examples/src/main/resources/people.json"` as parameter to `df = sqlContext.jsonFile(path)`

If you don't provide arguments when you run your python script, then it will go into `if len(sys.argv) < 2:`, this requires you to have defined `SPARK_HOME` as a system variable. If not, it won't find your specified .json file. Which seems to be your problem.

Comment: Have u tried that in your machine (windows)? It does not work on mine.

Comment: @teelou could you provide how you are running your python script? Are you passing valid arguments since you are using sys.argv? Have you defined location of SPARK_HOME?

Comment: @teelou try running your script from spark root folder without the "if statement" and define it as I defined path above. I'm guessing your path variable gets invalid because you probably have not declared SPARK_HOME as a SYSTEM VARIABLE.

Comment: An other fix would be defining the ABSOLUTE path (if you run shell from other location). This works for me on mac: path="<SPARK_HOME>/examples/src/main/resources/people.json"

Comment: `Have you defined location of SPARK_HOME? ` - how do I set SPARK_HOME with Python? I am new to this language.

Comment: You don't necessary need to do it via python, if you I think you need to run with administrator rights. You can do it manually as describe here: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

`os.system('your_command')` where the command would be `set SPARK_HOME=C:\spark_root_folder` you can read more here: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: But if you only want to check that your code works, I would recommend you to try (and without your if statement) run: `bin/pyspark` (if it's called pyspark on windows) from console in your **spark root folder**, then it should find the path I defined in my answer.