# How to set a global variable

Tags: python, variables

I tried to set a global variable in a funktion.
global the variable is set to `Kategorie = ''`

In one of my function I would like to set it to a other value:

```
elif methode=='show_select_dialog':
writeLog('Methode: show select dialog', level=xbmc.LOGDEBUG)
dialog = xbmcgui.Dialog()
cats = [__LS__(30120), __LS__(30121), __LS__(30122), __LS__(30123), __LS__(30116)]
ret = dialog.select(__LS__(30011), cats)

if ret == 6:
    refreshWidget()
elif 0 <= ret <= 5:
    writeLog('%s selected' % (cats[ret]), level=xbmc.LOGDEBUG)

    global Kategorie
    Kategorie = (cats[ret])        
    refreshWidget()
```

If I log the variable `Kategorie` in function `refreshWidget` the value is correct (`cats[ret]`), but after that if the function `refreshedWidget` is called again the value is gone...

```
elif methode == 'get_item_serienplaner':
sp_items = refreshWidget()
```

Once I have changed the variable to `cats[ret]` I would need it as `cats[ret]`

Comment: yes, that's a simple typo... it is also ``Kategorie``

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare your var outside your functions and everytime you want to use it inside a function you need to specify the `global varName`. As i see your global var name at declaration is **Kategory** and after you use **Kategorie**.

Answer (score 0):

Python wants to make sure that you really know that you are using global variables by explicitly requiring the **global** keyword.

To use a global variable within a function you have to explicitly delcare you are using it.

Here a small example:

```
myGlobalVar= 0

def set_globvar():
    global myGlobalVar    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    myGlobalVar = 5

def print_globvar():
    print myGlobalVar     # No need for global declaration to read value of myGlobalVar

set_globvar()
print_globvar()           # Prints 5
```

in your case I see that you declare that you want to access `global Kategorie` but you do not declare access to `global Kategory`. I do not know if this is a simple typo or if they are 2 different variable. In any case you need to write `global yourGlobalVariable`

Comment: So... did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: unfortunatally not... maybe I do not explain right. But I found a other way to solve the proplem. Now I use ``WINDOW.setProperty()`` and ``WINDOW.getProperty()`` and it works perfect for me...

Comment: ah so you wanted to set a system variable. have also a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Are there really any globals in python? Yes there is a global keyword that allows you to access varibles in file scope. Another way of accessing the variable is to use the import statement. Lets say you have a file named file.py. In order to write to the variable you could. You could access another files variables just as easy.

```
import file

anyVariable = 42

# ...
def aFunc():
    file.anyVarible = file.anyVarible + 1
```