# How do I add the path to a directory to the environment variables using python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I want to know if it is possible to add the path to a directory to the environment variables permanently using python. I have seen other questions that relate to mine but the answers there only add the path temporarily,I want to know if there's a way to add it permanently

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

This is what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)

Comment: No, I have a python program that needs marionette driver to run and the path to the driver has to be added to the env variables for it to run. So I want the program to automatically add the path to env variables if it isn't there already.

Comment: Do you mean `PYTHONPATH` (to find python modules) or `PATH` (for executing shell commands)?

Comment: @Levi PATH for executing shell commands

Answer (score 1):

While using bash add this 
`~/.bashrc`
`export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Home/dev/path`

Make sure the directory you point to has at the topmost `init.py` file in your directory structure

Comment: plus1 but just to clarify you need to restart or `source ~/.bashrc` so it will actually take effect

Comment: I need to add to PATH not PYTHONPATH