# Unable to run a octave function using oct2py through the web server

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

I am using oct2py to call a octave function in my python code. The file is saved as .py file in the htdocs folder.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import oct2py
from oct2py import octave
print('Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n')
print('<!DOCTYPE html>')
firnum='23'
secnum='33'
octave.addpath('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mypython/Octavemfiles/')
firnum=int(firnum)
secnum=int(secnum)
answer=octave.mymultfunct(firnum,secnum)
print(answer)
```

The code works well when executing from the terminal and gives the answer. But when I call it through the web, the oct2py gives an error stating

```
OSError: Octave Executable not found, please add to path or set"OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE" environment.
```

Please suggest a way out so I can call the function from octave. The octave function is just multiplying the numbers.

Comment: The error message tells you two possible ways to solve the problem. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: The webserver presumably does not run with the same environmental variables initialised as your local terminal. If you are unable to define OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE at the point of launching the webserver, perhaps you will be able to define it within python before importing oct2py itself (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python for an example of setting environment variables from within python)

Comment: I am new to this, how do I add path for Octave. The program  doesn't execute the line ' from oct2py import octave'. Thanks

Comment: @amathur have you tried importing via python as I said above? it would look something like `os.environ["OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE"] = "/path/to/your/octave/executable"` (assuming that your webserver has permission to access that path)

Comment: Is the package 'oct2py' installed in your runtime enviroment? (From the webserver)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux distribution:
**command : sudo pip install oct2py**
Error:

> > > import oct2py
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oct2py/**init**.py", line 38, in 
> > >           octave = Oct2Py()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oct2py/core.py", line 73, in **init**
> > >           self.restart()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oct2py/core.py", line 508, in restart
> > >           logger=self.logger)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/octave_kernel/kernel.py", line 157, in **init**
> > >           self.executable = self._get_executable()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/octave_kernel/kernel.py", line 432, in _get_executable
> > >           raise OSError(msg)
> > >       OSError: Octave Executable not found, please add to path or set"OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE" environment variable

**Solution
Please install octave using :
command : sudo apt-get install octave**

ubuntu@host:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import oct2py