# PyQt 5 and 4k screen

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, dpi

I'm trying to migrate an existing PyQt5 app to high-dpi for window 10.

The documentation of Qt5 itself speak about high-dpi scaling here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

```
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to "1".
```

But i can't adapt this in python code :/

Any idea ?

Comment: The Qt documentation says to set that parameter as an environment variable. So you'll want to have a look at this for how to do it in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5971312 make sure you do it before importing PyQt5.

Comment: I have tried `os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"`, which didn't change anything.
Then I found here http://bablabs.tistory.com/30 that I have to use `app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` additionally, but now i have the following error :
`AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'AA_EnableHighDpiScaling'`

Comment: That sounds like you're using an older Qt version which doesn't implement proper HighDPI support.

Comment: thanks, I'm using qt 5.4.1, and apparently hdpi support start with 5.6, I will try updating it asap :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you're on Qt 5.6+, [skim the docs to be aware](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html), then change your app init code to include one line before it and one line after it (written in Python) but it would be similar in C++:

```
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
qapp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
```

Comment: I am not sure this works for me.  If I move the window to monitors set at different scaling values, the size of the content in the window fluctuate significantly.  I expect the size of objects to appear about the same, or at least not truncate text in different windows.  Is this functionality version dependent?  Checking my versions as [described here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Getting%20the%20version%20numbers%20of%20Qt%2C%20SIP%20and%20PyQt), I have `QT_VERSION_STR: 5.9.4`, `PYQT_VERSION_STR: 5.9.2`, and `SIP_VERSION_STR: 4.19.8`.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell if you right-click the executable on Windows you can check compatibility settings on DPI scaling and try various values and see if that fixes it. Try also `os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "1"`

Comment: I am trying this within a QGIS plugin (Qt 5.11 & 5.15) and absolutely no joy, and I get crash after crash...  Does anyone have any insights on this?

Answer (score 3):

For me adding these three seemed to do the trick:

```
os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"]   = "1"
os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
os.environ["QT_SCALE_FACTOR"]             = "1"
```

The "QT_SCALE_FACTOR" was the one that was influencing the scaling the most for me.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful to others who find this thread, as I did, when I ran into similar problems.

I was primarily developing a `PyQt5` app on my Windows 10 laptop with a high dpi display. I noticed strange behavior when projecting my screen or moving the app to a different display in a dual monitor setup.  Basically, font sizes would change dramatically, and that caused all kinds of problems with the layout.

Ultimately, reading about [High DPI Desktop App Dev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows) from Windows got me to the solution.  They recommend using `Per-Monitor (V2) DPI Awareness`.  It seems that `Qt5` doesn't have support for this, [but Qt6 does](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html#configuring-windows), and it is set appropriately by default.

So merely upgrading my dependency on `PyQt5` to `PyQt6` solved my problems.  The version upgrade required some minor edits to my code.  One minor hiccup was that `QAction` moved to the `QtGui` module from `QtWidgets`.