# Running a bash script in python (Turning on MJPG STREAM)

Tags: python, bash, remote-access

I was cruising thru the topics, but anyway can´t get it working.

I need to turn on this bash script:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
>   ./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www"
>   -i "input_raspicam.so -x 640 -y 480 -fps 20 -ex night"

using `python`. I need a remote access to the `Raspberry Pi`, and writing this script to bash everytime I need to turn on the stream is just annoying. 
Any ideas how the code in `python` should look like?

Thank you guys.

Comment: You can set environment variables in python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python.  If you ran it as a bash script it would export it from the script but that would only be visible to the script's child processes.   Should there be a newline in there after the first `.`?

Comment: @cdarke Thank you for your answer, gonna take a look at it. Yeah there should be a new line, my bad.

Comment: You might also consider appending that variable to the .bashrc file of your Rasberry Pi user via a python script.

Comment: Thanks @BoboDarph

Comment: Also take a look at the `subprocess` standard module for running external programs.