# Where to store tokens/secrets with FastAPI/Python?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I'm working with FastAPI and Python on the backend to make external calls to a public API. After authentication, the public API gives an access token that grants access to a specific user's data. Where would be the best place to store/save this access token? I want to easily access it for all my future API calls with the public API service. I don't want a DB or long term storage as it only needs to last the session for the user. Appreciate all help!

Comment: I would probably store this as an encrypted cookie on the request session.

Comment: @flakes So I would use a requests.Session to store the token and then would I need to pull that token out of the cookie everytime to pass it to the public API in a GET request for example?

Comment: Yeah, that would be how I do it. Make sure the cookie is secured with a secret by the server, such that the cookie can't be parsed by client-side code to call your APIs directly.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this stuff. Could that mean storing a secret in the FastAPI/backend py files and then using that secret to encode and decode the cookie stored in requests.Session?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing secrets in the code, store them in environment variables which you set during deployment of the app.

Comment: @PeterHenry gotcha I will store my secrets in env vars, but do you know of a better way to store the access token, like maybe in a User class field that I can access across files for different API requests?

Comment: @oscar-lauth, try some of the options here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212497/storing-oauth-token-in-python-library

Comment: @PeterHenry thanks, I ended up storing client secrets/id (which are permanent) in .env and then creating a global User class that gets initialized and stores the access token as well as some other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost a year later, but I found a clean solution I was pleased with. I used Starlette's [SessionMiddleware](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#sessionmiddleware) to store the access_token and user session data in the backend.

Example:

```
from fastapi import Request
...
@router.get("/callback")
async def callback(request: Request):
 ...
 request.session["access_token"] = access_token
```

Then later, in any endpoints where I need to use the token or get session data:

```
@router.get("/top_artists")
async def get_top_songs(request: Request):
 ...
 access_token = request.session.get("access_token")
```

This stores access_token and any other session data you want on the backend. Then, a cookie, 'session_id', is stored client-side and passed through Request to retrieve the session data from the server.