# Setting environment environment variables with a Python script

Tags: python, linux, variables, operating-system, environment-variables

OS: Mac OSX 10.14
Python 2.7

I have a python script which looks like below:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os

os.system('./binaryfileproducesenv_variables > ./env_variables_file')
os.system('chmod 744 ./env_variables_file')
os.system('./env_variables_file')

os.system('python anotherpythonscript.py')
```

The env_variables_file looks like this:

```
passwordA='abcd';
passwordB='1234';
export passwordA passwordB
```

The anotherpythonscript.py will only work properly if the environment variables above are set properly. When i run it via the main python script it does not define the variables. Although, if i run the ./env_variables_file directly from the command line it will set the environment variables. Any suggestions how to run this through the Python script and have it set the environment variables.

Comment: `os.system('python anotherpythonscript.py')` - why do you do this? Why don't you just import it as a module and run the main function (if it was designed to run as script and has `if __name__="__main__": main()`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python I think this answers your question

Comment: I was looking at using os.environment, but the env_variables_file is a newly created file that needs to be created everytime (with new environemnts passwords) we want to run the anotherpythonscript.py script

Comment: if you use only `os.system` in python script then you should rather create bash script. You will have the same command but without `os.system`

Comment: `os.system('./env_variables_file')` doesn't do what you think it does.  Running a script sets the export in the one subshell. You need to read the file, and set each variable individually using `os.environ` before calling the next script. That said: just make a bash wrapper instead of a python one, reducing complexity and execution time.

Comment: Why in the world are you using python for this rather than a shell actually designed for this type of task such as bash or ksh? Also, using `os.system('some string') is the equivalent of `sh -c 'some string'` and isn't the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

See comment above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./binaryfileproducesenv_variables > ./env_variables_file
. ./env_variables_file
python anotherpythonscript.py
```

Comment: I wanted to stick to python but yeah a simple bash script is the way and makes more sense