# run setenv linux command in python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-os

I want to run setenv command through python script, the linux command is as below

`setenv MODEL path/to/the/model`

I tried using os.environ(), but I couldn't get the right syntax.

note - I'm using python 2.7

Comment: By `setenv`, I suppose you're referring to the csh builtin.  It's specific to `csh` and family.

Comment: Anything you run in a shell you start from Python only works *until that shell exits*; it won't change the environment of the Python interpreter, or the shell that started the Python interpreter.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, that's true, but even changing to use POSIX sh syntax, the command in question would still not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

os.environ isn't a function. Check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ

This question may also be helpful to you: [How to set environment variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python). If it is, pay attention to the comments on the top answer.

Comment: Duplicative questions should be closed, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "have already been asked and answered many times before".