# Connect Python to Bonsai

Tags: python, bonsai-elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to Bonsai using Python and for this I am using the code provided by Bonsai [here](https://docs.bonsai.io/article/102-python). However, my code breaks at

```
bonsai = os.environ['https://username:password@app-testing-3106893156.eu-central-1.bonsaisearch.net:443']
```

with error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'https://username:password@app-testing-3106893156.eu-central-1.bonsaisearch.net:443'
```

I am using the exact same code Bonsai provides and I am only adding the Full Access URL also provided by Bonsai so I have no idea how to proceed with this. Any ideas what is causing the error?

Comment: Disclaimer: I never used Bonsai, so take this as a guess rather than an answer. It just looks like `os.environ` (not a dict but is a mapping object so it's similar) doesn't have that url as a key. Looking over the link you provided, I'm suspecting the string `'BONSAI_URL'` is intended to be the key, not a stand-in for a full url. Try the code without the edit, maybe?

Comment: if you want to run without setting ENV variable then just assign the url to bonsai variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set environment variable first. example

```
export BONSAI_URL='https://username:password@app-testing-3106893156.eu-central-1.bonsaisearch.net:443'
```

and then use it in code like

```
bonsai = os.environ['BONSAI_URL']
```

Check [How to set environment variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)