# How do I restrict the number of processors used by the ridge regression model in sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to make a fair comparison between different machine learning models. However, I find that the ridge regression model will automatically use multiple processors and there is no parameter that I can restrict the number of used processors (such as n_jobs). Is there any possible way to solve this problem?

A minimal example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV

features, target = make_regression(n_samples=10000, n_features=1000)
r = RidgeCV()
r.fit(features, target)
print(r.score(features, target))
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the environmental variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to `n`, you will get the expected behaviour. E.g. on linux, do `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` in the terminal to  restrict the use to 1 cpu.

Depending on your system, you can also set it directly in python. See e.g. [How to set environment variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) for `RidgeCV`:

> Ridge regression with built-in cross-validation.
>
> By default, it performs Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation, which is a form of efficient Leave-One-Out cross-validation.

And by default you use `None` - to use the efficient *Leave-One-Out cross-validation*.

An alternate approach with `ridge regression` and `cross validation`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
clf = Ridge(a)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, features, target, cv=1, n_jobs=1)
print(scores)
```

See also the docs of [Ridge](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge) and [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to expand further on @PV8 answer, what happens whenever you instantiate an instance of `RidgeCV()` without explicitly setting `cv` parameter (as in your case) is that an Efficient Leave One Out cross-validation is run (according to the algorithms referenced [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L1113), implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L1076)).

On the other side, when explicitly passing `cv` parameter to `RidgeCV()` this happens:

```
  model = Ridge()
  parameters = {'alpha': [0.1, 1.0, 10.0]}
  gs = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=parameters)
  gs.fit(features, target)
  print(gs.best_score_)
```

(as you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/42aff4e2edd8e8887478f6ff1628f27de97be6a3/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L1652)), namely that you'll use `GridSearchCV` with default `n_jobs=None`.

Most importantly, as pointed out by one of `sklearn` core-dev [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9391), the issue you are experimenting might be not dependent on `sklearn`, but rather on

> [...] your numpy setup performing vectorized operations with parallelism.

(where vectorized operations are performed within the computationally efficient LOO cross-validation procedure that you are implicitly calling by not passing `cv` to `RidgeCV()`).

Answer (score -1):

Here it is try to take a look here [sklearn.utils.parallel_backend](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html) i think you can set up the number of cores for calculation using the njobs parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a useful measure.