# Why does sklearn RidgeCV not have an n_jobs argument?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Why does sklearn's `RidgeCV` not have `n_jobs` as an argument? `LassoCV` and `LogisticRegressionCV` both have it as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premise is that mine is just an *educated* guess; as you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14228) there's an ongoing attempt to enrich the documentation related to the use of `n_jobs`.

Nevertheless, the answer might be found in what is written in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-cross-validation-estimator) for cross-validation estimators:

> Some example of cross-validation estimators are ElasticNetCV and LogisticRegressionCV. Cross-validation estimators are named EstimatorCV and tend to be roughly equivalent to GridSearchCV(Estimator(), ...). The advantage of using a cross-validation estimator over the canonical estimator class along with grid search is that they can take advantage of warm-starting by reusing precomputed results in the previous steps of the cross-validation process. This generally leads to speed improvements. **An exception is the RidgeCV class, which can instead perform efficient Leave-One-Out CV.**

Basically, the use of `RidgeCV` slightly differs from the use of the other cross-validation estimators (among which, for  instance, `LogisticRegressionCV`, `LassoCV`, `ElasticNetCV`).

- the former (whenever used with default `cv=None`) implements [Ridge regression with built-in Leave-one-out Cross-Validation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3ea3ed6a09fe774dfc5160a65172b1bacbb2a82/sklearn/linear_model/_ridge.py#L1629); whenever `cv is not None`, instead, it implements `GridSearchCV(Ridge())` with default `n_jobs=None`.
- the latter ones do implement more standard cv-strategies with the advantages described above with respect to the use of `GridSearchCV(Estimator())`.

Eventually, some other useful information might be found in this recent [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377950/how-do-i-restrict-the-number-of-processors-used-by-the-ridge-regression-model-in).