# How to set `n_jobs` in sklearn ElasticNet

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib, lasso-regression

I am trying to run the [ElasticNet function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html) from `scikit-learn` on a machine with multiple CPUs. However, I need the ElasticNet fit to only use one CPU, since I need to run other fitting routines in parallel on the remaining CPUs. Whenever the thread containing `ElasticNet` starts the fit, it quickly takes over any free space on all CPUs instead of just the one its called on. Because other code routines are running on these machines already, `ElasticNet` oversubscribes the machines and slows everything down tremendously, including itself. I need these routines to run in parallel, so I cannot just run the `ElasticNet` fit serially ahead of time.

Unlike other regression functions (linear, logistic...) in `sklearn` there is no `n_jobs` argument for `ElasticNet`. Reading [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html), it appears that `ElasticNet` defaults to the `n_jobs` specified in `joblib.parallel_backend` which itself defaults to `n_jobs=-1`, which is all available CPUs.

I am trying to figure out the proper method for specifying `n_jobs` in `parallel_backend` so that it will override the default for `ElasticNet`. Following are three attempts to change `n_jobs` that have not worked so far.

**Attempt 1**

```py
from joblib import parallel_backend
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

with parallel_backend('loky', n_jobs=1):
                    
    model = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, fit_intercept=False, 
                       normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=10000, tol=10,
                       random_state=42, precompute=False, warm_start=False,
                       positive=False, selection='cyclic')
    model.fit(predictors, response)
```

**Attempt 2**

```py
from sklearn.utils import parallel_backend
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

with parallel_backend('loky', n_jobs=1):
                    
    model = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, fit_intercept=False, 
                       normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=10000, tol=10,
                       random_state=42, precompute=False, warm_start=False,
                       positive=False, selection='cyclic')
    model.fit(predictors, response)
```

Both Attempt 1 and Attempt 2 do not throw any errors, but also do not appear to change `n_jobs` from the default of using every available CPU. `ElasticNet` still takes over all available CPU space across all CPUs and quickly oversubscribes the machines.

**Attempt 3**

This is my first time using `joblib` directly, and so I've been reading [the documentation](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) on parallelization with joblib. Most of the example routines placed in the `parallel_backend` container are prefaced with the [`Parallel()` helper class](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html).
Following the examples, I modified Attempt 1 in the following way:

```py
from joblib import parallel_backend
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

with parallel_backend('loky', n_jobs=1):
                    
    model = ElasticNet(alpha=alpha, l1_ratio=l1_ratio, fit_intercept=False, 
                       normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=10000, tol=10,
                       random_state=42, precompute=False, warm_start=False,
                       positive=False, selection='cyclic')
    Parallel(n_jobs=1)(model.fit(predictors, response))
```

However when running Attempt 3, I get the following error message:

```py
TypeError: 'ElasticNet' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know how to set `n_jobs=1` for sklearn's `ElasticNet`? There must be some way to do this because `ElasticNetCV` has `n_jobs` as a possible argument. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: May the accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377950/how-do-i-restrict-the-number-of-processors-used-by-the-ridge-regression-model-in/) help?

Comment: Thanks amiola! I can't figure out a way to set the global variable since I am running python on all machines, and I don't want to force those jobs to run serially on just the one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first solution, you can manually set `MKL_NUM_THREADS=1` by

```
import mkl
mkl.set_num_threads(1)
```