# How do I change an environment variable only during tests in Django?

Tags: django

I have a class that extends the root `TestCase`. I would like to set an environment variable in each of the tests that extend this class so that I don't cycles on unnecessary API queries.

When I place the patch decorator outside of the class, it appears to have no effect.

When I place the patch decorator just above the setUp, the patch appears to only last through the duration of the setUp.

```
import mock, os
from django.test import TestCase


#patching here seems to have no effect
class TCommerceTestCase(TestCase):

  @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {
    "INSIDE_TEST": "True"
  })
  def setUp(self):
    self.assertEqual(os.environ["INSIDE_TEST"], "True") # works!

  def test_inside_test(self):
    self.assertEqual(os.environ["INSIDE_TEST"], "True") # Fails!
```

How do I patch an environment variable in a Django test (without manually patching to every function?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in that way:

````py
import mock, os
from django.test import TestCase

class TCommerceTestCase(TestCase):

  @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {
    "INSIDE_TEST": "True"
  })
  def test_inside_test(self):
    self.assertEqual(os.environ["INSIDE_TEST"], "True")
    ```
````

Comment: Yes this does work for `test_inside_test`, but is there a way to apply os.environ["INSIDE_TEST"] to *every* test?

Comment: Please don't be confused about adding a short decorator to all needed tests. It is OK. Every developer/tester who reads a code of a test will be understanding that behaviour was changed by a decorator.  It's short - just copy/paste it.

Comment: Understood. I am looking for a DRY solution

Comment: DRY principle is not for testing. Testing principle is repeating, hardcoding, avoiding any logic and complicity.

Comment: Good news! It is possible to implement DRY principles during testing. This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66384229/3869506