# Trouble understanding Bash and translating to Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to translate this from Bash to Python:

```
export file="${directory}/scrutation_$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S").log"
```

I know that `export` sets an environment variable, and that `(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")` is `strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")` in Python.

This is what I have tried:

```
import os
os.environ[file]= f"{directory}/scrutation[strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")].log"
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know if it's intentional, but the f-string is invalid, the outer `""` should be changed to `''`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python.

Comment: Like so? 
`f'{directory}/scrutation[strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")].log'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the environment variable is a string, it needs to be quoted.

Double quotes aren't nested in `f""`, use single quotes for one of the pairs.

`$(...)` is the Command Substitution, i.e. you need to run the `strftime`, not include it in square brackets.

Also, you can use the same format string without changes, unless you really want to change the timestamp format.

```
os.environ['file'] = f'{directory}/scrutation_' \
    f'{datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")}.log'
```