# set environment variable in python script

Tags: python, export

I have a bash script that sets an environment variable an runs a command

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=my_path
sqsub -np $1 /homedir/anotherdir/executable
```

Now I want to use python instead of bash, because I want to compute some of the arguments that I am passing to the command.

I have tried

```
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "my_path")
```

and

```
call("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=my_path")
```

followed by

```
call("sqsub -np " + var1 + "/homedir/anotherdir/executable")
```

but always the program gives up because LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for help!

(if I export LD_LIBRARY_PATH before calling the python script everything works, but I would like python to determine the path and set the environment variable to the correct value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [change current process environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178094/change-current-process-environment)

Comment: @S.Lott: can you please explain how I can apply that thread to my problem? (cause I do not understand it)

Comment: @S.Lott (addentum): in particular the excepted answer in that thread starts with "the reason os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] does not work" and in my case it works

Answer (score 110, accepted):

bash:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=my_path
sqsub -np $1 /path/to/executable
```

Similar, in Python:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "my_path" # visible in this process + all children
subprocess.check_call(['sqsub', '-np', sys.argv[1], '/path/to/executable'],
                      env=dict(os.environ, SQSUB_VAR="visible in this subprocess"))
```

Comment: subprocess.check_call(command, env=os.environ)  'module' object has no attribute 'check_call', I'll try using call for now

Comment: I would avoid a such solution, because it mutates the current process environment. Better pass a copy of it to the child process.

Comment: the explanation is critical here: visible in this process + all children

Comment: @rdesgroppes: I've added an option (`env`) where the updated environment is visible only in the child process (`$SQSUB_VAR` in the current process' environment remains unaffected)

Comment: Could this applied for the `HOME` path as well?

Answer (score 22):

You can add elements to your environment by using

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = 'my_path'
```

and run subprocesses in a shell (that uses your `os.environ`) by using

```
subprocess.call('sqsub -np ' + var1 + '/homedir/anotherdir/executable', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 22):

There are many good answers here but you should avoid at all cost to pass untrusted variables to subprocess using `shell=True` as **this is a security risk**. The variables can escape to the shell and run arbitrary commands! If you just can't avoid it at least use python3's `shlex.quote()` to escape the string (if you have multiple space-separated arguments, quote each split instead of the full string).

`shell=False` is always the default where you pass an argument array.

Now the **safe** solutions...

### Method #1

Change your own process's environment - the new environment will apply to **python itself and all subprocesses.**

```
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = 'my_path'
command = ['sqsub', '-np', var1, '/homedir/anotherdir/executable']
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

### Method #2

Make a copy of the environment and pass is to the childen. You have total control over the children environment and won't affect python's own environment.

```
myenv = os.environ.copy()
myenv['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = 'my_path'
command = ['sqsub', '-np', var1, '/homedir/anotherdir/executable']
subprocess.check_call(command, env=myenv)
```

### Method #3

Unix only: Execute `env` to set the environment variable. More cumbersome if you have many variables to modify  and not portabe, but like #2 you retain full control over python and children environments.

```
command = ['env', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=my_path', 'sqsub', '-np', var1, '/homedir/anotherdir/executable']
subprocess.check_call(command)
```

---

Of course if `var1` contain multiple space-separated argument they will now be passed as a single argument with spaces. To retain original behavior with `shell=True` you must compose a command array that contain the splitted string:

```
command = ['sqsub', '-np'] + var1.split() + ['/homedir/anotherdir/executable']
```