# Multiple environment variable to run before running shell script in python

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to export multiple path to unix environment before execution followed by multiple script execution on same parent process. Any feedback on be python code while running on the server

```
import os, subprocess
os.environ['PATHLOC'] = '/home/sys/data/'
os.environ['LOC'] = '/home/tool/dev'
os.environ['ROOT'] = '/servername/data/code'

r1 = subprocess.run(['sh','/home/script/scriptname.sh', 'arg1'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.stdout)

if r1 == 0:
    r2 = subprocess.run(['sh','/home/script/scriptname2.sh', 'arg1'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.stdout)
else: 
    print('Process 1 failed : {}'.format(r1))

if r2 <> 0
    print('Process 2 failed : {}'.format(r2))
```

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Comment: "*Any feedback on be python code while running on the server*" -- is this working code you want to improve? Consider posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: export path are not being picked during script execution. these part are parameterized path used inside the script during execution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set environment variable in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365394/set-environment-variable-in-python-script)

Comment: Btw its important to describe what the intended behavior of your program is and what isn't working when you post a question. This permits more relevant answers. Your question originally asked for "*feedback on be python code*".