# iPython: imported module can't find its shared libraries

Tags: python, shared-libraries, ipython, gurobi

In iPython, I import a module, which in turn imports another module. This another module (namely gurobipy) tries to load its shared library, which fails. The path to the shared library is added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in .bashrc. When I run the whole thing as a script from the shell, everything is fine.

I googled for a while now but didn't find the ultimate answer to the question: how do I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in iPython such that imported modules will see it?

I tried os.environ but still got the same error message: `ImportError: libgurobi50.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

EDIT: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: How are you starting IPython? If you start it from a terminal, it should get the same environment variables. You should be able to modify environment variables using [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I'm starting from the Unity launcher. You're right, when started from a terminal, it works. I am able to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH with os.environ. However, when I then import the module, it still does not find the library.

Comment: Possibly LD_LIBRARY_PATH has to be set before the process starts.

Answer (score 2):

Try including LD_LIBRARY_PATH to a system-wide file. For instance, /etc/profile  (at the end of it). For instance this is what I needed to add for my case:

export NEVESIM_HOME=/home/kam/Applications/Nevesim

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${NEVESIM_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

Be careful with the syntax. Also you have to re-log in to make the changes active.
For more help see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well. I would, however, be really curious to know if it can be done from within the python script itself or from within an iPython shell.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime library path is configured when the python (or IPython) interpreter starts up. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856116/changing-ld-library-path-at-runtime-for-ctypes).

It seems that tools like ctypes use this path when searching for libraries. Likewise, if a module depends on a particular library, it will search this path when it's imported or run.

This is true for any process, not just IPython. You can't just change the loader path while a process is running. [Also read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178094/change-current-process-environment).

If you think about it, that's really a good thing. It could cause all kinds of problems. All of the sudden, the process can't find a library it needs, and crashes.

This is unfortunate, though, as it means that IPython can't really be used as a full shell replacement.

I'm not sure how shells such as BASH handle this. I imagine that BASH uses one runtime path for itself, and exports another for processes run inside it.