# VSCode does not update environment variables upon .env modification

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, .env, vscode-python, python-dotenv

I'm using .env in a Python project, with python-dotenv, but it seems like VSCode automatically loads the environment variables from the .env.

Unfortunately, VSCode does not seem to update the environment variables when I modify the .env file, causing the Python program to run on old environment vars.

Restarting VSCode / opening new integrated terminals does not seem to help. It looks as if it caches the .env somewhere, and reloads it from cache, without removing the cache when the original file is updated.

Output of /usr/bin/env together with .env file:

[image]

Output of Help: About:

```
Version: 1.84.0-insider (Universal)
Commit: f1c3b1dcf85e3b6ddb24b7dce0e4b122e8ce6233
Date: 2023-10-17T05:38:23.658Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 22.6.0
```

Python extension version `v2023.19.12931008`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Also add the version number of your Python extension. Then add an _exact_ procedure that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: please also check if anything in the first page or two of https://www.google.com/search?q=github+vscode+issues+python+%22.env%22+update matches your issue.

Comment: @starball I've checked, thanks. Unfortunately, all of the issues are closed, and I'm running the latest build. I've seen them before, but this is a little mind boggling. It seems like the env file is being re-read when I restart vscode, use the developer reload-window, and open a new integrated terminal. If I miss any step it does not reload.
It's rather difficult to add an exact procedure that reproduces it. It's simply a dotenv not being loaded to the environment (only after restarts etc.)

Comment: I'd suggest to raise a bug ticket using `Help > Report Issue` in the menu bar. If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket and put as much detail as you can into your issue ticket.

Answer (score 6):

Came accross same issue today.
It really looks like VSCode caches values somewhere, and pre-initializes the terminal with environment from cached (outdated `.env`).
The workaround is to use `override=True` in `load_dotenv()`.
Surely, looks like a bug.

Comment: VSCode should not do this kind of operation it could have very bad outcomes. For example, you are changing environment variables from production to testing database... you could perform operations that you may regret in the future

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your Python code is getting environment variables, but this is how I usually do.

.env

```
BROADCAST_MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
DEFAULT_MAC=11:22:33:44:55:66
```

config.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
import os

# path to your .env file
env_path = Path(".") / ".env"
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

class Config: # Save your var in a class
    BROADCAST_MAC = os.getenv("BROADCAST_MAC")
    DEFAULT_MAC = os.getenv("DEFAULT_MAC")
```

main.py

```
import config

BROADCAST_MAC = config.Config.BROADCAST_MAC
DEFAULT_MAC = config.Config.DEFAULT_MAC
```

I personally like separated file for configurations (easier to debug).
Let me know if this helped, if not, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354400/22761053) might help

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help. Unfortunately, the environment is loaded with vscode, even before python is running. It has nothing to do with the Python code :-)