Use dotenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH in python-tkinter
I am new to python-tkinter. I am trying to load a library in tkinter tcl interpreter. However, I am not able to use environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH which I am setting using dotenv.
Here is the sample of .env file which I am using:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/pkg/boost_lib/
Use of this .env file:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv("<Absolute path of my .env file>")
ld_path = os.getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
print(ld_path) /// it prints the correct path /pkg/boost_lib

However, load command in tcl interpreter is not working.
tcl_intr.eval('load <my_lib>')
It works fine when I set this LD_LIBRARY_PATH on terminal outside my python program.
I am expecting it to work within python program.

This seems similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/856287/7212665

and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178094/change-current-process-environments-ld-library-path
