# How to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm attempting to run a flask app with mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm having a problem setting the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH$` environment variable. I'm able to set this in my `~.bashrc` file, and as a result I am able to import all my libraries and dependencies without a problem. However it seems apache seems to erase these environment variables.

The error I'm getting in my log file is the following

```
ImportError: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

There are two python libraries I'm importing that require mkl. The first doesn't seem to complain. However the second library cannot be imported due to the mkl error.

I find this odd so I recompiled the second python library after setting the `$LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable to the mkl paths. However it is still unable to find mkl.

How do I configure apache accordingly? All other imports work fine. I am able to run the flask scripts on their own without apache, so I'm pretty sure this is an apache problem.

Comment: If you are confident you set ``LD_RUN_PATH`` correctly when compiling any libraries or Python modules which needed ``libmk_rt.so`` and ``ldd`` on those binaries show it being correctly found without having ``LD_LIBRARY_PATH`` being set, the problem may be that the library or directory it is in may not be readable to the user that Apache runs your code as.

Comment: I ran ldd on the library and the mkl library path showed up. What does this mean?

Comment: I actually realized I'm having import errors on other libraries as well. It seems as though apache can't find many other python libraries.

Answer (score 4):

if in you

```
/etc/sysconfig/httpd
```

add something like this

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/library/path
```

then

```
apachectl restart httpd
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

apache by default use system lib path. so just add link of your so file to `/usr/lib` and then run command `sudo ldconfig`. perhaps problem will resolve

also this post may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/23244452/6876911

Comment: How do I add the link. mkl is in the `/opt` directory

Comment: I tried the post you linked and added the path in directly but it still didn't work

Comment: @user3543300 `sudo ln -s <src> <dst>`. what dose you do exactly?