# AWS lambda unable to find ODBC Library while using pypyodbc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pypyodbc

I'm trying to make the connection to sqlserver using pypyodbc library, but my lambda throws following error

```
module initialization error: 'ODBC Library is not found. Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH set?'
```

Is there something i need to upload to layer apart from pypyodbc library?
Any help or guidance will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to import pypyodbc module gives error 'ODBC Library is not found. Is LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH set?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825966/trying-to-import-pypyodbc-module-gives-error-odbc-library-is-not-found-is-ld-l)