# What is the right way to ship dynamic library *.so with python package?

Tags: python

I have a package require `a.so` which load `b.so` and load it by `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(a_so_path)`.

So I have to ship them with my package.

Here are two idea for it.

1. set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to my site-package

Now the problem is, how can I change lib load path in the runtime, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my module will not work(refer to [Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before importing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244418/set-ld-library-path-before-importing-in-python)). But it is a package, I can not make every user load python in a shell script which set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  to `***/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypackage/lib/`.

2. install `*.so` to system lib

I found `data_files` in `setup.cfg` can distribute files out of site-packages ( to `/usr/lib` where can be find). But unfortunately, it not support egg or wheel package. see https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#id55

So, what is the right way to release my package?

Comment: I believe you want to build a [wheel](https://pythonwheels.com).

Comment: @chepner, I have build a wheel, but where should I place the so files? Root directory of my package?

Comment: I was under the impression that the shared libraries were included *in* the wheel, and that `pip` takes care of installing the wheel properly for you.

Comment: Or are you asking where they should be installed within the wheel in the first place?

Comment: You can include `package_data` option for `setup` function to specify the files you want to ship with.  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#data-files-support.  The you can use either `importlib.resources` or `pkg_resources` module to find the location of the files in the package.

Comment: I would wonder if .so files work in all platforms. Don't you have to compile them for separate environment?

Comment: @chepner, @Kota Mori, the problem is not I can not contain `*.so` in package but I can't load them when import. The only way I know to import so any where is set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before python process start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways in question could not work. I finally choose change `RUNPATH` of my dynamic library.

Use `patchelf` ( or `chrpath` if your `*.so` already have `RUNPATH`), put all dynamic libraries in one folder and run:

```sh
find . -name "*.so" | xargs -l1 -t patchelf --set-rpath "\$ORIGIN"
```

Dynamic library will search depends in `RUNPATH` while `"\$ORIGIN"` means *current binary path*, so if we put all `*.so` in one directory, depended `*.so` will be found.

then package them in wheel use

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    ...
    package_data={
        # If any package contains *.so, include them:
        "": ["*.so",],
    }
)
```

now, everything works.