# Python seems unable to find hid library on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, hid, macports

When I set up a python virtual environment and install the hid module it doesn't seem able to find a library that I've installed with MacPorts. I'm running Mac OS Big Sur 11.6.1 and I've also installed python with MacPorts. Any troubleshooting ideas?

```
comp:~ me$ virtualenv-3.9 vtest
created virtual environment CPython3.9.8.final.0-64 in 475ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/me/vtest, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/me/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.3.1, setuptools==58.3.0, wheel==0.37.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
comp:~ me$ source vtest/bin/activate
(vtest) comp:~ me$ python3 -m pip install hid
Collecting hid
  Using cached hid-1.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: hid
Successfully installed hid-1.0.4
(vtest) comp:~ me$ python3 -c "import hid"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/me/vtest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hid/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise ImportError(error)
ImportError: Unable to load any of the following libraries:libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll
(vtest) comp:~ me$ for i in libhidapi-hidraw.so libhidapi-hidraw.so.0 libhidapi-libusb.so libhidapi-libusb.so.0 libhidapi-iohidmanager.so libhidapi-iohidmanager.so.0 libhidapi.dylib hidapi.dll libhidapi-0.dll;do find /opt -name "$i";done
/opt/local/lib/libhidapi.dylib
```

Update: hidapi is installed with MacPorts:

```
(vtest) comp:~ me$ sudo port installed | grep hid
  hidapi @0.9.0_0 (active)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpreter in your virtual environment is supposed to be segregated from the dependencies on your machine (to a point), so in that sense, it is working as designed.

Check out [Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before importing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244418/set-ld-library-path-before-importing-in-python). This should get you going.

Comment: Thanks, setting that before starting python seems to get things moving along!

Answer (score 1):

So your problem in fact isn't that your python can't find the `hid` package.

When importing `hid`, `hid` tries to load native libraries that are not installed. this can be solved (on MacOS) using `brew install hidapi`
as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/hid/)

Comment: As shown by the last line in my code block I do have that library installed. I've added an update to the question.