# Convince Python-CFFI to find shared lib

Tags: python, python-cffi

I have a somewhat strange setup:
I have a libmylib.so I cannot modify, but, since the interface is rather convoluted, I wrote a simple wrapper directly into `ffbuilder.set_source()`

My full `lib_builder.py` is:

```py
import os
from cffi import FFI
ffibuilder = FFI()

ffibuilder.cdef("""
int start(int port);
int ready(void);
int publish(char *buf, int len);
int stop(void);
""")

ffibuilder.set_source('_mylib_cffi', """
#include "mylib.h"

static uint32_t handle = 0xffffffff;
int start(int port) {
    mylib_init(0);
    mylib_register_publisher("127.0.0.1", port, &handle, 0);
    return 1;
}
int ready(void) {
    return handle != 0xffffffff;
}
int publish(char *buf, int len) {
    return mylib_publish(handle, buf, len);
}
int stop(void) {
    mylib_shutdown();
    return 1;
}
""", libraries=['mylib'], library_dirs=[os.path.dirname(__file__)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ffibuilder.compile(verbose=True)
```

This works as expected but my test code:

```py
import _mylib_cffi
...
```

bombs because `libmylib.so` is not found (it is in current directory, exactly where generated `_mylib_cffi.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` is located).

I can make it work either moving `libmylib.so` to `/usr/lib` (or other directory in the system lib search path) or adding current directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Both solutions are not particularly appealing to me because I don't want to pollute system settings with needs of a single program.

Is there some way to dynamically load needed lib from within Python?

Note: I'm trying to learn Python-CFFI, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with GCC on Linux, you can avoid the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` hack (described in your own answer to the question) with the linker's `-rpath` option.  I think what you need is:

```
ffibuilder.set_source(..., extra_link_args=['-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN'])
```

I didn't test it, but I think this should make CFFI produce the glue `.so` in such a way that this `.so` should look for `libmylib.so` in the same directory as where it is.

On Windows, I think nothing is needed: a DLL always (by default) tries to look for other DLLs it depends on in the same directory.

Comment: Will that work also on Mac (with GCC)?

Comment: Something similar exists, but I think in the osx variant it's setting rpath to %ORIGIN instead. You will have to Google for more details...

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25457751/1714490) I was able to make it work using:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
if 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    try:
        # print('restarting...')
        os.execve(sys.argv[0], sys.argv, os.environ)
    except Exception as exc:
        print('Failed re-exec:', exc)
        sys.exit(1)
# else:
#     print(f'LD_LIBRARY_PATH={os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]}')

import struct
import time
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from xml.etree import ElementTree

import _mylib_cffi
...
```

I will not accept my own answer though, hoping for a less convoluted strategy.

One evident drawback is this won't work under Windows (yes, I have a `libmylib.dll` equivalent to `libmylib.so`) and it would be beneficial to have a multi-platform solution.